# StreamWriter throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I simply want to write data from a listBox to a textfile. The name of the textfile should include the current date and time.

```
string filename = String.Concat(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Today), "_", string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now), ".txt");
System.IO.StreamWriter fs = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, false);
foreach (var item in myLbx.Items)
{
    fs.WriteLine(item);
}
fs.Close();
```

When I run this code, I get a `NotSupportedException`, saying that the format of my filename is not supported.

Comment: you must use path.Combine(...)

Comment: First of all it would really help if you could show us the actual file name. And second you could try creating a file in the Explorer containing a ':' character (I'm assuming your current culture uses that as time seperator) and see what happens.

Comment: filename = "2014-07-18_09:12:33.txt"

Comment: And yes, you are right. It seems that ":" is not so cool. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a file with a name that has reserved characters, such as `:` or `<` in the filename. You must use another character for your colons.

Comment: Noticed you just got the answer in the comment! Feel free to post an answer Dirk!